# Webmaster Tools shows Internal Links from old site (not ours)

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

In the Google Webmaster Tools account of my latest project I can see 57 Internal Links (links to internal pages), that are not actually from our site. Since we just launched it, there are no real internal links, only these "fake" ones.

My only guess is that at some point in the past, someone used that domain name, and now these links live somewhere in the internet and currently lead to 404 page in our site.

So my question is, how to tell Google that these links are not actually part of our site and they have never been ?

Comment: "now these links live somewhere in the internet" - If these are listed under "internal links" then they previously existed on your domain. If they are "somewhere in the internet" then they would be listed under "external links".

Comment: Links to these old internal pages exist somewhere, because I can see traffic coming to these URL's in my cms platform.

Comment: Ah, I think I've misinterpreted your question... you are referring to _external links to the old site_ as reported in the _external_ links report in GWT? As opposed to "internal links from old site"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is a registrar so they know when a domain changes hands and *probably* can tell which links are for the old site and which are for the new site. But, assuming they do not, you can [disavow these links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) in your GWT account.

Comment: Disavowing (what were once) **internal** links does seem to go against the grain? Normal procedure to remove an internal link is to simply... remove it. So that it no longer exists. And since this is an entirely new site (on an old domain) then it already no longer exists?

Comment: Yes, these pages doesnt exist for quite some time now (at least 4 month, when I bought the domain)
Should I do something about them, or just wait google to realize that they are not from the same site ?
Is it possible for google to be mistaking my absolutely new site as a "new version" of the site that was once on this domain, and if yes, what can I do about it?

Comment: Four months is a long time. I'm surprised Google hasn't written those pages off already. You might want to [manually remove them from Google's index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663416) just to get rid of this error message once and for all.

Comment: Errm, I think I've (misinterpreted) taken the question text too literally ... these are external links to _internal_ pages? In which case disavow away (or simply ignore if the inbound links are not spam-like). As long that these _external (inbound) links_ exist to your site then GWT will continue to report them (as 404s).

Comment: Thank you John Conde, I will go for manually removing them from google's index. Hopefully that will be enough.
Is it possible this to be harming my potential ranking in google? The site is new and I'm hoping that someday it will have a decent ranking. I believe I've made my on-page seo almost perfect, following latest instructions(as in seo everything changes quickly) for markup, best practices and etc.

Comment: I doubt this is hurting your site. But cleaning this up is definitely a good idea. Always better safe then sorry.